# Is there an easier way to install package from GitHub release, than building from source?

Tags: command-line, apt, github

I'm very new to all things Linux so please bear with me. I'm trying to install the [latest release of pgrouting](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/releases/tag/pgrouting-2.1.0) and my steps are as follows:

```
sudo mkdir pgrouting
cd pgrouting
sudo wget https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/archive/pgrouting-2.1.0.zip
sudo unzip pgrouting-2.1.0.zip
cd pgrouting-pgrouting-2.1.0
sudo mkdir build
cd build
sudo cmake ..
sudo make
sudo make install
```

So basically I am downloading, unzipping and building it from source. But since there's a GitHub release, is there a way to install it using apt-get without building from source?

Comment: Ask the devs to build packages for you, and perhaps create a PPA? What does the Github release have to do with packaging?

Comment: Aside: your `mkdir`, `wget`, `unzip` and `make` commands shouldn't be using `sudo`. Only the `make install` command should need it.

Comment: What's a PPA and once created how do I use it with apt-get? Thanks!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/4983/158442 and https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA

Comment: Thanks! Another useful link is this: http://askubuntu.com/q/370636/511276. Basically short answer to my question is that GH releases are about tagged versions of source and are not about binary packages needed for installation with apt-get

Answer (score 1):

Link shared by muru answers my question: https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading
I need to create and upload a PPA to install it with apt-get but looks like the effort in my case wouldn't be justified, building from source is easier.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested asking the devs to do it. They can probably automate it with git hooks.